# Can you use cleanse while being grabbed by Blitzcrank?

Tags: league-of-legends

This is Blitzcrank. He has the ability to grab stuff (including champions):

[image: Blitz grabbing Ryze]

This ability is a pain in bot lane.

I was just wondering. Can cleanse be used while being grabbed by Blitzcrank?

Bonus cookie: Is there anything that can stop the champion from being pulled and be used mid-grab?

EDIT on bonus cookie part: That includes champion abilities on **both sides**. Tho this was answered in comments, I was thinking towards skills like Anivias wall, LeeSins ulti, Alistars pulverize, Skarners ulti etc.

Comment: Fairly certain the answer is no, Cleanse has the same effect as a quicksilver sash, except it can cancel out summoner spells, or portions of the summoner spell. Quicksilver sash doesn't negate grabs or knockups.

Comment: There are a few champion that can blink out of there, like Ezreal. If you time it right you can get hit by the hand but not pulled

Comment: I can agree with certain champions being able to, I've personally canceled out a Darius grab as Caitlyn by .90 Caliber Netting at the same time, ending up in the same spot i was originally in.

Comment: @Ravekner "Cleanse has the same effect as quicksilver sash".  Sorry, this is wrong.  QSS cancels supresses, among other things, that Cleanse does not. (WW, malz ults)

Comment: my bad, should have said "almost" the same effect, obviously there are differences between the two.

Comment: I would just add that Sivir's shield also blocks the pull. It is actually pretty funny to use the enemy blitz as a mana potion when you can lure him into grabbing you often and being fast enough on the shield =)

Comment: You can use ezreal's E or tristana's jump anything that moves your position

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll answer strictly for the bonus :)

Basically everyone is right when they tell you that no, cleanse **will not** work when being grabbed by blitzcrank.  You can't use stuff "mid-grab", but you can use certain blinks when you see him start the ability which can then land you in some pretty weird situations.

Then, there's spell-shields.  Morganna, Sivir and Nocturne's spell shields block the displacement of a blitz pull.

But one thing that hasn't been mentioned:

*"Is there anything that can stop the champion from being pulled"*

Absolutely, [Banshee's Veil](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Banshee%27s_Veil) will do the trick!  Underrated item!

**EDIT** speaking of bonus cookies, check [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hbuaq7Q_bYo) out, lol...

Comment: How about Anivias wall? I have seen it stop Nocturne mid-ulti...

Comment: @TheBW that is not really helpful, but i have seen pulls get aborted by alistar pulverize/headbutt(even though in lvl 30 areas you seldom see ali-blitz combo so badly played ;)), also you could be grabbed mid-air by some other champ like thresh or malz, which will "override" the blitz-pull

Comment: Is it still possible to place a ward so he grabs that instead of you? Or did they remove it like being to block rammus's roll?

Comment: Lyrion - I am certain that that does not work on wards. Vogel the Anivia could be on you team and helping out. The override part was what I was interested there! Thanks.

Comment: @TheBW as Blitz can grab through "terrain" as which anivia wall is handled, he will grab you even through anivia's wall... what could work is thresh's lantern

Comment: Thresh's lantern shouldn't prevent you from being pulled, but if Thresh throws it out right it could get you back out quickly. Assuming it's not a team fight with a zillion stuns to seal your doom.

Comment: The anivia wall could've been placed as the nocturne was flying. If anivia puts it right on top of herself and doesn't move, nocturne will land on the otherside. There was also a hotfix to fix an issue where anivias wall was blocking all movement abilities(trynd spin, noc ult and stuff like that.

Answer (score 4):

Forced Movement effects are essentially suppressions for the duration of the movement. For knockups, this is until the champion lands. For x/z movement, it lasts until the movement finishes (or would have finished, since it's possible for a secondary forced movement effect to interrupt the first).

As such, there is no way to avoid or reduce forced movement, since summoner spells of all kinds are unavailable while stunned or suppressed.

Comment: Blitzcrank grabbing a Blitzcrank that's grabbing another champion, always funny to see. Both grabbed champions end up at the first Blitzcrank's location.

Comment: `As such, there is no way to avoid or reduce forced movement, since summoner spells of all kinds are unavailable while stunned or suppressed.` Wrong. For example, mosts CCs, including stun and airborne, can't prevent Smite. That's why baron stealing is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have found out that many barriers can block blitz's pull.  Such as if blitz is trapped in veigars trap, you  cant pull anything into it with you.  Thresh's lantern also stops it.